# Is JQuery necessary for Angular when I use Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, angular, bootstrap-5

I knew that the interactive event-driven things like clicking, hover effects, modals etc. on Bootstrap, we need JQuery. Are there any alternatives by which we can completely avoid JQuery when we are using Bootstrap with Angular Projects?

Comment: You dont need. But if you want to use Bootstrap components like dropdown or modal, you need to write your own js using angular directive. Instead, try with https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular is a full scale framework with its own libraries to handle all sorts of interactivity related tasks (clicking, hover effects, modals) **and you'd not need jQuery to achieve the same**.

Comment: But bootstrap needs jquery rite?

Comment: Use the angular bootstrap module. npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Comment: Thanks @Obaid for the suggessions. I did the ng-bootstrap modal for a navbar and its working 100%

Comment: @Maharan If this solved your problem, then please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Zze : Yeah, Thanks for reminding